# NSMutable dictionary is nil NSJSONSeralization

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I have this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

and when the internet connection goes (I am using airplane mode).

I get an error saying responseObject is nil.

I have put this code in straight after it:

```
if (responseObject == nil){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self ProvidePopUpForNetworkLoss];
    });
}
```

I am getting the error:

****Terminiating this app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason 'data parameter is nil'
can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you show the line that is causing the error ?

Comment: The top line in my message is lit up in purple and it says response object is nil as the error.

Comment: Please provide some more code

Comment: Can you show where `data` comes from? The problem is probably prior to the code you showed.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not data which is nil ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have no internet connection (or for many other reasons) "data" (wherever you got it from) will be nil. JSONObjectWithData correctly says that it is a programming error to call this method with nil data and throws this exception. Solution: Don't call JSONObjectWithData if the data isn't nil. Anyway, this error should be treated very differently from JSONObjectWithData returning nil. If JSONObjectWithData returns nil, it means there was something wrong with the data you received.

To find where your problem is, create an exception breakpoint in Xcode. It will stop when the exception is thrown, and that would show you which method threw the exception - it's before your nil check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .Maybe this will help you. and check that the object you get from data is dictionary or not.

```
if(!data)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self ProvidePopUpForNetworkLoss];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

||Try this modification:

```
if (responseObject == [NSNull null] || responseObject == NULL){
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self ProvidePopUpForNetworkLoss];
});
}
```

Comment: None of this worked, I am getting ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: Have you check your API url.

Comment: it works fine until i remove the internet connection. so it works a treat until i put my phone on airplane mode.

Comment: The answer is quite useless, because JSONObjectWithData will never return [NSNull null] (unless you gave it a parameter to allow parsing of JSON fragments _and_ you give it a fragment that says "null"), and you don't get a "parameter is nil" exception if you pass [NSNull null] to a method.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internet connection then response data will be nil, Try to print response string or error in logs, so that you can have clear idea

```
NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"htmlSTR=%@",htmlSTR);
```

and

```
NSLog(@"Error=%@",[error localizedDescription]);
```